# why is mpi slower on my laptop

Tags: performance, mpi

I am running MPI on my laptop (intel i7 quad core 4700m 12Gb RAM) and the efficiency drops even for codes that involve no inter-process communication. Obviously I cannot just throw 100 processes at it since my machine is only quad-core, but I thought that it should scale well up to 8 process (intel quad core simulates as 8???). For example consider the simple toy Fortran code:

```
program test
implicit none
integer, parameter :: root=0
integer :: ierr,rank,nproc,tt,i
integer :: n=100000
real :: s=0.0,tstart,tend
complex, dimension(100000/nproc) :: u=2.0,v=0.0

call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,nproc,ierr)

call cpu_time(tstart)

do tt=1,200000
  v=0.0
  do i=1,100000/nproc
    v(i) = v(i) + 0.1*u(i)
  enddo
enddo

call cpu_time(tend)

if (rank==root) then
  print *, 'total time was: ',tend-tstart
endif

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

end subroutine test2
```

For 2 processes it takes half the time, but even trying 4 processes (should be quarter of the time?) the result begins to become less efficient and for 8 processes there is no improvement whatsoever. Basically I am wondering if this is just because I am running on a laptop and has something to do with shared memory, or if I am making some fundamental mistake in my code. Thanks

Note: In the above example I manually change the nproc in the array declaration and the inner loop to be equal to the number of processors I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quad core processor, thanks to hyperthreading shows itself as having 8 threads, but physically they are just 4 cores. The other 4 are scheduled by the hardware itself using the free slots in the execution pipelines.

It happens that especially with compute intensive loads this approach does not pay at all, being often counter-productive too on extreme loads because of overheads and not always optimized cache usage.

You can try to disable hyperthreading in the BIOS and compare it: you will have just 4 threads, 4 cores.

Even going from 1 to 4 there are resources that are being in competition. In particular each core has its own L1 cache, but each pair of cores shares the L2 cache (2x256KB) and the 4 cores share the L3 cache.

And all the cores obviously share the memory channels.

So you cannot expect to have linear scaling occupying more and more cores, since they will have to balance the usage of the resources, that are dedicated to one core/one thread in the sequential case.

All of this without involving communications at all.

The same behavior happens on desktops/servers, in particular for memory-intensive loads, as the one in your test case.

For example it's less evident with matrix-matrix multiplies, that is compute-intensive: for a NxN matrix, you have O(N^2) memory accesses but O(N^3) floating point operations.